# How should you observe Ekadashi and Pradosh fasts when these fall on consecutive days (so Parana for Ekadashi is after sunrise on the day of Pradosh)?

Tags: shiva, fasting, ekadashi

Sometimes Parana for Ekadashi falls after sunrise on the same day as Pradosh/Pradosham. For example, here (in Tokyo) Ekadashi was on Dec. 4 and Pradosh was Dec. 5, then Ekadashi was Dec. 20 and Pradosh was Dec. 21 - it's happened quite a lot recently, and more than I'd expected.

On these occasions, what's the best way to observe both events? Should people fast for two straight days? Even if they do that, it would surely violate the requirement to break one's Ekadashi fast during Dwadashi. Or is it unusual to observe both?